# Cannot horizontally align images in print preview

Tags: html, css, alignment

i have two images shown in the browser which is horizontally align. my objective is to print them using javascript however the preview shows that the 2nd image is going under the first image as if it has a new line. What I need is to print this pictures horizontally align. I also tried adjusting the padding-top to align them but it doesnt work.

```
<img id = "telin_logo" class="responsive-img" src="img/telin.jpg" style="width: 133px;height: 77">
<img id = "telin_logo2" class="responsive-img" src="img/telin.jpg" style="width: 133px;height: 77px;">
```

what I mean by print is printing by printer. i used @media print to adjust the layout. sorry for missing out this information

Answer (score 0):

my solution is purely based on css . you can see my snippet . i hope it helps you .

```css
.container{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #222;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
body,html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.left{
    width:50%;
    float:left
}
.right{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
<p style="text-align:center"><img src="red.png"/></p>
</div>
<div class="right">
<p style="text-align:center"><img src="red.png"/></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below properties.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 77px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/133x77/CCCCCC&text=telin_logo">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/133x77/CCCCCC&text=telin_logo2">
</div>
```